# Switching from Visual Studio Community 2022 to Visual Studio Professional 2022 breaks CMake build for CUDA language

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda, visual-studio-2022

When switching from VS 2022 Community -> Professional editions, my CMake build broke for my CUDA language files. My CMake version is 3.23.1, and my CUDA SDK is version 11.6.

The error I get is "No CUDA toolset found".

I got a similar error when upgrading from VS Community 2019 -> 2022, which I fixed by uninstalling my (then) CUDA SDK 11.4, and replacing it with 11.6.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Any time you install a version of VS, its necessary to do a CUDA toolkit install, after that point, in order for CUDA to be usable in that new install of VS.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for your input—why is it necessary? Is reinstalling the same version enough?

Comment: It's necessary because the CUDA installer locates specific files and directories in your VS install and puts additional assets there, such as the "props" file.  These additional assets are necessary for VS to be able to create and recognize CUDA projects correctly, and built CUDA codes correctly.  Yes, in many cases, reinstalling the same version is enough as long as it is compatible with the particular VS you just installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I fixed this by uninstalling my CUDA 11.6 SDK and replacing it with CUDA 11.7, which theoretically is also compatible with the same drivers as the last version.